# Carousal image is showing different size

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I have given same size images in carousal card but when its showing to directline channel first image showing small but azure bot its showing correctly.

[image: Direcline Image]

Comment: Does azure bot mean Team Channel or Test in Web chat?

Comment: in web chat its getting. why first image is small for all carousal. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Directline is part of your own custom web chat window but other channels have their own capability to control their own UI.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? If not, can you update your post to include the code you are using for generating the carousal, including image links or specific details about each image?

Comment: Also, it is possible to affect the look of the carousal card elements via CSS if you need to force a specific design or feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These cards are rendered in different channels and every channel has the capability to control its own UI. Probably that could be the reason the card is properly aligned in the web chat channel.

Create your own css for the directline channel.